# Windows Dark Title Bar in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, ide, titlebar

I have a dark theme in IntelliJ Idea and a super annoying white title bar, how do I change my title bar's color without messing with system wide settings?

I use Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer. On the desktop right click, then select Personalize, then click Colors on the right sidebar, then in the "Show accent color in the fallowing surfaces" section select title bars.

After that go into InteliJ, in `File` `>` `Settings`, click on plug-ins, select "browse repositories", search for Material Theme, and you install the plug-in. After you restart your IDE, in the Material Theme Wizzard you'll find a setting for the themed title bar.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 2018.3 IntelliJ IDEA does not support a dark title bar on Windows. There's an [open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-192816) tracking this.

Answer (score 0):

now IntelliJ supports this check **Appearance -> Use dark window headers.**
[IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/06/intellij-idea-eap-5-dark-window-headers-on-macos/)